# UITapGestureRecognizer partially works on UIImageView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a table view. Some cells could have images, and I add those images to cells through UIImageView. Those images have react and open new view controller if a user taps it (not a cell). Images are of different size.

I added UITapGestureRecognizer to UIImageView, but it acts weird. I thought the whole area of imageView will respond to gestures, but I see only some smaller areas, and on all images this area is located differently.

Here is the code from cell init:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier

    UIImageView *thumbnailImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
    thumbnailImageView.tag = CELL_THUMBNAIL_TAG;
    thumbnailImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [self.contentView addSubview:thumbnailImageView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *pictureTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePictureTap:)];
    [thumbnailImageView addGestureRecognizer:pictureTap];
    [pictureTap release];
```

All the cells with images are displayed correctly in different orientation
Location of images and texts inside cells is done through *layoutSubviews* method:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
if (thumbnail) {
    CGRect thumbnailFrame = CGRectMake(contentOrigin.x, contentOrigin.y, thumbnail.size.width, thumbnail.size.height);
    thumbnailImageView = (UIImageView *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:CELL_THUMBNAIL_TAG];
    thumbnailImageView.frame = thumbnailFrame;
    thumbnailImageView.image = thumbnail;
```

}

In *tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:* method I just pass all the required data to the cell, so the whole configuration is going in layoutSubviews

Could you please help me identify why the area that reacts on tap gesture is defined randomly and strange for all imageViews, despite that all content is displayed correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After long list of ideas I finally found the reason of that strange behavior. It might help anybody with similar problem.

In this project I subclass UITableViewCell. Since all cells could be of different size, I provide correct height in tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath: method.

HOWEVER, in my custom cell init method I didn't set proper autoresizing mask. That lead to UITableViewCellContenView view had constant height of 44pt. And this view is a superview for all cell content.

I don't know why despite of it all cell content was displayed correctly and with proper sizes, but all gestures reached imageView only within this 44pt height area.

Setting

```
self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

in custom UITableViewCell init method I solved this issue.

Comment: I had the same issue, very strange behaviour of uitableviewcells

Comment: Thanks!

In one table I used the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` callback, and that works fine even with custom heights. But when I used the tap recognizer in another table I got this strange behavior.

Comment: This bug also happens with UICollectionViewCell, and can be fixed by this answer as well. Something weird, this bug only happen when I build my app with Xcode 6 beta and launch the app in iOS 7. iOS 8 is totally fine. Or if I build my app with Xcode 5 and it's fine too.